# How to Delete all Photos in android Device

Tags: android, mediastore

I have the following code to delete all photos in the `DCIM` folder and `download` folder:

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = new String[] {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, 
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
if (cur != null) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        File path =new File(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));
        path.delete();
    }
    cur.close();
}
```

But this code did not delete the photos in the Gallery app which you can find it in applications menu.

Do you have any idea how can I delete all the photos in the android device at once?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the following permission.
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
in AndroidManifest.xml file

But are you really sure you want to delete all users photos?

Comment: but what was your question? This is not an universal solution. This helped the original problem. Please take your time to write a question or describe your problem.

Comment: How can you know? The answer did not get accepted and no feedback was provided! I have the same exact problem with deleting pictures stored on the internal storage which leads me to believe it is not an issue of permissions at all.